# CUDA C++ How to programs to benchmark shared memory bandwidth?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, benchmarking, gpu-shared-memory

I'm looking for a way to benchmark shared memory and L1/L2 cache. However, the benchmark results I found are very different depending on the source.

In this paper, [Dissecting the NVIDIA Volta GPU Architecture via Microbenchmarking](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.06826.pdf), they show shared memory bandwidth to be 12000GB/s on Tesla V100, but they don't provide how they reached that number. If I use [gpumembench](https://github.com/ekondis/gpumembench) on a NVIDIA A30, I only get ~5000GB/s.

Is there any other sample programs I can use to benchmark shared memory?

Comment: Nvidia Nsight Compute has for a lot of performance indicators the reachable maximum stored.

Comment: After a first glance I would guess that the difference is that in the benchmark they read and write and count it only once. What is your GPU model?

Comment: @Sebastian I'm benchmarking NVIDIA Ampere A30 with 24GB. I can't find any detailed information like in that paper about that GPU

Comment: If the shared memory layout was kept the same for the Ampere (32x 4 byte banks/SM), the A30 with 56 SMs and 930 (base)-1440 MHz (boost clock) has a theoretical shared memory speed of 6666 GB/s to 10322 GB/s (combined over all SMs). In the paper the achieved speed was about 1/8 less than the theoretical maximum. So you would get 5835 to 9035 GB/s in benchmarks with the A30 compared to up to 12080 GB/s (boost) with the V100 - mostly due to its 80 SMs. You should take the clock speed of the GPU during the benchmark into consideration. And run it with Nvidia Nsight Compute for added information.

Comment: For benchmarking you could consider using at least 64 bit accesses to shared memory to lower the probability of MIO throttles.